# Magento "Shop By" feature is showing but not working. How to fix this?

Tags: magento

I'm on magento 1.9.1.0

For some reason the "Shop By" feature is not filtering the products when used.
You can check it out here: http://www.eccellente.nl/ontkalken

The page refreshes but all products are still shown.

Does anyone have a clue to why this would happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright - I figured out that Full Page Cache was the problem.
Needed to add the specific attribute to the Full Page Cache extension in order to make it work.